# JTDS driver - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: DB server closed connection.)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am attempting to connect to an SQL database hosted in Azure from a piece of software I'm using on an Azure VM, using the JTDS JDBC Driver.

This isn't software I have built/am developing, this is a third party program I am using to view my data. In the software I create data sources using JDBC drivers. The issue may be with the software I am using, but I wondered what other issues could cause this problem?

I am using the following connection url:

> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[servername]:1433/[databasename];user=xxxxx;password=xxxxx
>
> driver: jtds-1.3.1.jar
>
> class:  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
>
> Response: Could not connect to 'URLSTRING' with User Id 'xxxxx'. This probably means that the URL or login details are incorrect. The full error is: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: DB server closed connection.) SQL Exception : null

The database firewall is configured to allow the IP of my VM and I can `telnet` to the port fine.

- I have connected to this database, on this port, using the JDBC 4 driver from within this same software.
- The software suggests it's a username and password issue, and wrong credentials also throws the same error. I am wondering if I am passing the username and password wrong?

Comment: Instead of coding username and password into the URL, you could use the (URL, user, password) typed call to connect. Can you share code how you setup connectionfactory?

Comment: @Jan I'm sorry, I wan't clear. This isn't software I am developing, this is a piece of 3rd party software I am using to view my data. So therefore I don't setup connection factory. I fill out a datasource connection page within the software. This question is more about the structure of my connection url as put to the software I am using

Comment: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat lists the properties provided - and user and password are correct so far.